# How to make a class-based custom element side-effect-free so webpack only bundles the explicitly imported components

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules, tree-shaking

I have a set of spec v1 custom elements which I'm using webpack 4 to bundle (and babel-loader to transpile).

The components all look similar to this:

```
export class CompDiv extends HTMLDivElement {
  constructor(...args) {
    const self = super(...args);
    self.property = null;
    return self;
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('connected CompDiv');
  }
}

customElements.define('comp-div', CompDiv, { extends: 'div' });
```

Now to be able to create custom packages from these components using selective, named imports I need to mark these files as [side-effect-free](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#mark-the-file-as-side-effect-free).

The component registration, though, takes place in the module itself:

```
customElements.define('comp-div', CompDiv, { extends: 'div' });
```

As far as I understand, that **is** a sideeffect.

Now I have an `index.js` that basically looks like this:

```
export { CompDiv } from './components/comp-div/comp-div';
...
export { CompBtn } from './components/comp-btn/comp-btn';
```

My webpack entry point looks like this:

```
import 'document-register-element';
import 'babel-polyfill';
import { CompDiv } from './index';
```

Now when I do this, `CompBtn` (and all other exports in index.js) ends up being part of the bundle even though it's not imported in my webpack entry point.

What would be the recommended way of allowing for treeshaking in webpack with these web components?

Comment: Have you set `sideEffects` package.json property to `false` ?

Comment: @Fraction Of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From webpack guide - [Mark the file as side-effect-free](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#mark-the-file-as-side-effect-free):

> All the code noted above does not contain side effects, so we can simply mark the property as false to **inform webpack that it can safely prune unused exports**.

So, setting `"sideEffects": false` in `package.json` tells webpack that your modules are side effect free. So that it can prune unused exports (in your case, unused re-exports). This is generally used by *library authors*.

But that's just one side of the equation.

From webpack configuration docs - [`optimization.sideEffects`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization#optimizationsideeffects):

> Tells webpack to recognise the [`sideEffects`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/examples/side-effects/README.md) flag in `package.json` or rules to skip over modules which are flagged to contain no side effects when exports are not used.

So, in order to leverage that previously mentioned option, the *library consumer* will have to set the `optimization.sideEffects` option to `true` in their webpack config file:

```js
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  ...
  optimization: {
    sideEffects: true
  }
  ...
}
```

Note that, in [`production` mode](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode), this option is enabled by default. So, you'll only need to set it for `development` mode.

**N.B.**: In this case, you are both the *author* and the *consumer* of your modules.

Lastly, let's look at your webpack entrypoint:

```js
// webpack entrypoint
import 'document-register-element';
import 'babel-polyfill';
import { CompDiv } from './index';
```

If you don't use your imported `CompDiv` later in this file, webpack will prune it - assuming you've set `"sideEffects": false` in `package.json` and `optimization.sideEffects` to `true` in your webpack config.

But, for example, even if you *only* imported `'babel-polyfill'` and won't explicitly use anything from it later in this file, webpack will not prune it, because the `package.json` for `babel-polyfill` library doesn't contain `"sideEffects": false`.

I hope that clears things up.

Comment: But how is the custom element registration *not* a side-effect?

Comment: @connexo It is a side-effect. But we are just telling webpack to not worry about it. If you actually want to make the module without any side-effect, you'll have to do something like this:

```export function registerComDiv() {
   customElements.define('comp-div', CompDiv, { extends: 'div' });
}```

And later import and invoke that function when you want to register it.